# VHDL State Machine for LCD initialization

Tags: simulation, vhdl, state-machine, spartan

I'm trying to implement the initialization of a LCD of the Spartan 3AN. I'm very new to this so every advise is very welcome.

My code is as follows:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Company: 
-- Engineer: 
-- 
-- Create Date:    17:31:49 11/04/2011 
-- Design Name: 
-- Module Name:    LCD - Behavioral 
-- Project Name: 
-- Target Devices: 
-- Tool versions: 
-- Description: 
--
-- Dependencies: 
--
-- Revision: 
-- Revision 0.01 - File Created
-- Additional Comments: 
--
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
--use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
--use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity LCD is
    Port ( clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
           LCD_DB : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
           LCD_E : out  STD_LOGIC;
           LCD_RS : out  STD_LOGIC;
           LCD_RW : out  STD_LOGIC);
end LCD;

architecture Behavioral of LCD is

--      CAUTION!!!  When using 4-bit mode, FPGA must drive the LCD_DB<3:0> signals HIGH ( = '1' )   
--      MAQUINA DE ESTADOS INICIALIZACION
    type initialization_state is (A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, done);
    signal iCurrentState: initialization_state := A;
    signal iNextState: initialization_state := A;
    signal cycleCounter: integer := 0;

--      MAQUINA DE ESTADOS

begin

    initializationLCD:
    process (clk) begin
        if (clk'event and clk = '1') then
            case iCurrentState is
                when A =>
                    if (cycleCounter = 750000) then
                        iCurrentState <= B;
                        cycleCounter <= 0;
                    else
                        cycleCounter <= cycleCounter + 1;
                    end if;
                when B =>
                    LCD_RS <= '1';
                    LCD_RW <= '0';
                    LCD_DB <= "00000001";
                    if (cycleCounter = 50000) then
                        iCurrentState <= C;
                        cycleCounter <= 0;
                    else
                        cycleCounter <= cycleCounter + 1;
                    end if;
                when C =>
                    if (cycleCounter = 50000) then
                        iCurrentState <= D;
                        cycleCounter <= 0;
                    else
                        cycleCounter <= cycleCounter + 1;
                    end if;
                when D =>
                    LCD_RS <= '1';
                    LCD_RW <= '0';
                    LCD_DB <= "00000010";
                    if (cycleCounter = 50000) then
                        iCurrentState <= E;
                        cycleCounter <= 0;
                    else
                        cycleCounter <= cycleCounter + 1;
                    end if;
                when E =>
                    if (cycleCounter = 50000) then
                        iCurrentState <= F;
                        cycleCounter <= 0;
                    else
                        cycleCounter <= cycleCounter + 1;
                    end if;
                when F =>
                    LCD_RS <= '1';
                    LCD_RW <= '0';
                    LCD_DB <= "00000100";
                    if (cycleCounter = 12) then
                        iCurrentState <= G;
                        cycleCounter <= 0;
                    else
                        cycleCounter <= cycleCounter + 1;
                    end if;
                when G =>
                    if (cycleCounter = 50000) then
                        iCurrentState <= H;
                        cycleCounter <= 0;
                    else
                        cycleCounter <= cycleCounter + 1;
                    end if;
                when H =>
                    LCD_RS <= '1';
                    LCD_RW <= '0';
                    LCD_DB <= "00001000";
                    if (cycleCounter = 12) then
                        iCurrentState <= I;
                        cycleCounter <= 0;
                    else
                        cycleCounter <= cycleCounter + 1;
                    end if;
                when I =>
                    if (cycleCounter = 50000) then
                        iCurrentState <= done;
                        cycleCounter <= 0;
                    else
                        cycleCounter <= cycleCounter + 1;
                    end if;
                when others =>
                    iCurrentState <= done;
            end case;
        end if;
    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

So there are 2 questions:

1. Is this code fine? I know I have much more code to do but I just want to see if I'm doing well, what takes me to question 2
2. I simulated with ISim (BTW I'm on Xilinx 12.3) and the state never changes always is A, is my code missing something? or maybe I'm simulating this the wrong way, can you tell me how to simulate it?

Thanks so much !

Comment: Do you have a proper clock signal and is cycleCounter incrementing?  You may just not be waiting long enough...750000 cycles of _anything_ in the simulator is going to take a while.

Comment: The clock is 50 Mhz. In the simulation I put a period of 20 ns. But as I said nothing seems to happen. I think I'm not simulating well this thing. How can I simulate it?

Comment: Don't use `IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL` nor `IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL` - they are NOT IEEE standard and deprecated. Use `numeric_std` - internet search that term for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things I see, some are style, some are not:

1. Do **not** use the `std_logic_arith` and `std_logic_unsigned` libraries - they are **not** IEEE standard, and can really hurt beginners because it takes away a lot of the strong types the VHDL provides. Use `numeric_std` instead. An internet search can tell you more.
2. The "modern" macro `rising_edge()` is preferred for clock checking because it also handles the L->H state (which in an FPGA/ASIC never happens, but anyway...)
3. You have a `iNextState` which seems to be unused.
4. You have a boundary condition where none of the `LCD` outputs are set on startup. Either add a reset to the FSM, or you need to re-think the way the outputs are set (cf. Mealy vs Moore style FSMs).
5. If you have an enumeration for `initialization_state` you might want to give them more meaningful names and/or comment on what they're supposed to be doing at each state.

Otherwise, a quick look seems fine. As others noted, 750K clocks is a *long* simulation, and without seeing the testbench code that drives the clock, we have no idea if it will work. I'd recommend switching the 750K and all the others into constants that you can change to very small values for testing purposes.

Comment: Ok I'll try to not use those libraries and correct the states' names. One thing that I don't know if it's right... When doing FSM a friend told me to have 2 processes: 1 for the change from current to next state, and another one for the transitions... In my code, for me, I think is not necessary 2 processes or am I wrong? The state transition can be achieved as I have it in my code?   Finally, when I simulate this I have always for iCurrentState the value of A... it never changes, is it due to the 750000 cycles?

Comment: I'll add the code for the testbench, do you have a tutorial on how to simulate a FSM on Xilinx's Isim? Thanks a lot ! Maybe the code is fine maybe I'm simulating wrong.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed I was simulating wrong. Just clicking buttons around lsim and reading and trying to understand solved my little problem.